# Does the Airbus A320 or Boeing 737 have better resolution screens in the cockpit?

Tags: avionics, airbus-a320, boeing-737

I know this is kind of a specific question so if nobody knows it's fine. Does anybody know if the Airbus A320 or Boeing 737 has better resolution cockpit screens like PFD and ND? ( For the Airbus A320 I also mean the new screens like some A320 have more circular cockpit screens and the new ones are more square and look more defined

Here's the new screens, well it's not new but it's better 
[image: New Screens]
Here is the more circular screen 
[image: Old Screens]

Comment: I made edits to the title, but I also recommend that you also crop the pictures so that the pictures only (or relevant labels) are visible. Simply attempting to ascertain which picture refers to to plane was quite difficult.

Comment: Which 737? There's three different 737 generations with different displays, the Classic, NG and MAX. The new screens you refer to on the A320 is called the EIS2, which are LCD versus the CRT of the EIS1.

Comment: By better resolution screen do you simply mean higher resolution or are you looking for a higher pixel density?

Answer (score 8):

B737NG DUs (Display Unit) have a resolution of 1152x1152, as per the maintenance manual. The display size is 18x18cm, making it around 163 PPI.

I have found a [source](https://bitbarrelmedia.wordpress.com/2017/11/01/real-time-efis-vector-graphics/) that claims A320 PFD has a resolution of 768x768 and the display size is 158mmx158mm, making it around 123.4 PPI.

I imagine B737 MAX is using the same 15.1" display as the [B787](http://www.sharp-world.com/corporate/news/120420.html). In this case, the resolution is 1400x1050, and the PPI would be around 116 PPI.

Comment: Of course 737-NG is some 10 years newer than A320, so using slightly better screens are to be expected.

Comment: Actually, the displays on the 737NG are probably roughly the same as for the B777, so they are not that new. Add to that, the first A320 with LCD display units was produced in 2009, whereas before that, the A320s were equipped with CRT displays.

Comment: They are not that new, but still a couple of years newer than A320. Yes, I know A320 was originally CRTs, and thought they didn't want to change the resolution when switching to the LCDs to avoid having touch the software, but than I realised they touched the software anyway, because the newer version comes with somewhat simplified symbology.

Comment: I wonder where one could get those square LCD panels. They'd make a wonderful HAL-9000-like workstation.

Comment: @rbanffy or use a cheap consumer 27" display and put a plate with square cutouts in front of it. That's how many home cockpit builders go along.

Comment: That's cheating, @Emile.