# What are the A320 ECAM system displays' dimensions?

Tags: airbus-a320, ecam

I am a student taking up an Aeronautical engineering course. We were assigned to draw A320 ECAM system pages. However, I have a difficulty finding the dimensions for each of the system pages.

What are the dimensions for the ECAM system pages?

Comment: Why not ask your professor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/91186/where-can-i-find-a-description-of-the-ecam-system-pages

Comment: Also see: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/51333/does-the-airbus-a320-or-boeing-737-have-better-resolution-screens-in-the-cockpit

Besides individual system pages, you are probably interested in https://www.smartcockpit.com/docs/A319-320-321-Indicating_and_Recording.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You’re not looking for different sizes here, each of the 12 ECAM system pages is displayed on the lower ECAM display unit (DU) so they’re all the same size.  As I recall A320 DU’s are about 160mm x 160mm but I’ll get my tape measure out when I’m sat in front of one on Monday

Comment: Personally I don’t normally use French measurements of length hence the confusion